# How to awoid flickering in ImageView with Ripple-Background

Tags: java, android, animation

I've downloaded this libary from github to get a ripple-effect on my View.
[RippleBackground](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background)

If I set the RippleBackground width to `android:layout_width="200px"` (see the activity_main.xml) the view starts to flicker. (Same result if i set margin)
                Strange thing is if i set background color to black the Ripple-Effect work properly. How can i avoid this?

This class is for the Ripple-Background: [RippleBackground.java](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/skyfishjy/library/RippleBackground.java)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.testripple3.MainActivity">

<com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    app:rb_color="#0099CC"
    app:rb_radius="32dp"
    app:rb_rippleAmount="4"
    app:rb_duration="3000"
    app:rb_scale="6">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/centerImage"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</com.skyfishjy.library.RippleBackground>
```

MainActivity.java

```
final RippleBackground rippleBackground=(RippleBackground)findViewById(R.id.content);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.centerImage);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
}
    });
```